# Sum of numbers that equal 100

Tags: performance, ruby

I was asked to find all the numbers that added up to 100 with no duplicates in Ruby. I float between Python, GoLang, and Ruby in a day. I am always concerned if I am doing something in the most optimal way.

```
require 'pp'
sumdata = [ 95, 5, 95, 5 ]

def find_sum(data)
  result = []
  processed = []
  data.each_with_index do |item, index |
    next if processed.include? index
    data.each_with_index do |other, other_index|
      next if processed.include? other_index # next if already processed
      # add tuple to list
      if item + other == 100
        result << [item, other].sort
        processed << index
        processed << other_index
      end
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Do you mean no duplicates in the results, or in the inputs? For example, if your input in the above had `50, 50` on the end, would that count as a legitimate way to get 100 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to sorting input data, this one is faster, than @Zack's one.

```
def find_sum data, target_sum
  sorted = data.sort
  [].tap do |result|
    sorted.size.times do |index|
      first, *rest = sorted.drop(index)
      (1..rest.length).each do |n|
        next if target_sum < rest.take(n).inject(first, :+)
        rest.combination(n).each_with_index do |arr, i|
          result.push [first, *arr] if target_sum == arr.inject(first, :+)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

0.0013sec vs 2.0sec

Making it recursive (`break` on any depth) could achieve the optimal speed, but such solution becomes not that so easy to read as Ruby code should be.

Comment: @Nakilion I'm getting different results for your function passing `find_sum( (1..9).to_a, 10)` and `find_sum( (1..9).to_a.shuffle, 10)`

Comment: @Zack, indeed, had two bugs. Now should work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of solutions and insights I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is built assuming you want no duplicates in the results, since the goal is a little unclear.

#### Quickly Finding Combinations

The function you should be using is `Array.combination(n)`, which generates an enumerator that yields all combinations of size `n` from the array.  Once you have that it is a trivial matter to only select the combinations that sum to the target value.

My function here finds all combinations of size 2 to size `data.length` and then selects only the combinations with the correct sum.

```
def find_sum(data, target_sum)
  (2..data.length)
    .flat_map { |n| data.combination(n).to_a }
    .select { |arr| arr.inject(:+) == target_sum }
    #.uniq   # can call this to remove duplicates if necessary, depending on what the input data looks like
end

data = (1..9).to_a
pp find_sum(data, 10)
#[[1, 9],
# [2, 8],
# [3, 7],
# [4, 6],
# [1, 2, 7],
# [1, 3, 6],
# [1, 4, 5],
# [2, 3, 5],
# [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This method can be converted to lazy like this: `.lazy.flat_map { |n| data.combination(n).lazy}`.

Comment: @tokland  I thought about adding `lazy` but thought that there would be no benefit because the entire sequence has to be iterated. I suppose it might cut down on memory overhead?

Comment: Yes, as the question stands, the only advantage is that no intermediate arrays would be created.